# Wordpress if/while or while loop

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, while-loop

When including the standard wordpress loop, when do I need to use the 'if have posts, while have posts, the post' or the 'while have posts, the post' ?

Do I always need to use the if/while, or is it just on some pages that I need to use just the while loop ?

I feel that I have included the if/while on all pages and if that is the appropriate way...

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

The Loop is a PHP code used by WordPress to display posts. Using The Loop, WordPress processes each post to be displayed on the current page, and formats it according to how it matches specified criteria within The Loop tags. Any HTML or PHP code in the Loop will be processed on each post.

I know in some cases if the condition is not required but WordPress Alway prefer to use if condition before the loop.

Especially I always recommended if condition when you use the `wp_query`.

For more information Here I have shared the WordPress official [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/the_loop).